# Unable to set marginTop style with script using IE8, but works in grown-up people browsers

Tags: javascript, html, css, internet-explorer

I'm attempting to animate the slide-out of a menu with script.  To do this, I need to animate the `marginTop` property of an element and increment it from `-30px` to `0px`.

However, in IE8, the animation simply does nothing.  I've traced this down to the fact that setting `marginTop` in script seems to have no effect.  In Chrome and Firefox, this works fine.

Here's an example that will work with Chrome/Firefox, but not IE:

http://jsfiddle.net/rm58T/2/

Is this an IE bug, and if so, are there any workarounds for this behavior?  Thanks!

**Update:**

Here's some screen shots of the bug.

In Chrome, my Fiddle looks like this (You can see the "Name of new menu" text, since we changed the margin with script)

[image]

In IE8/Vista, it looks like this.  I can confirm in Developer Tools that `topMargin` is actually `0px` as expected, however the elements were not re-drawn:

[image]

**Another Update:**

This bug repros (at least for me) on IE8 running on Windows 7, and also IE8 running on Windows 2008 Server.  It does NOT repro for me on IE7 running on WinXP.  I do not have any IE9 machines to test it.

**Yet Another Update:**

I found one potential work-around.  If I set `p.newmenu` to `position: absolute;` instead of `position: relative;` then it works.  However, in my case I'm hosting this entire thing in a popup menu and need this control to push out the bottom of the modal dialog, so absolutely positioning it is not an option.  However, perhaps this knowledge can help in finding a workable solution.  An example of this work around can be found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rm58T/11/).

**Would You Believe Another Update?:**

I *did* find a workaround for now.  If I use `top: -30px;` instead of a negative top margin, then everything works.  `top` behaves a bit differently than a margin, though, and makes the UI not look quite as nice.  In particular, when you use `top: -30px`, then you'll have 30px of whitespace under your element since relative positioning doesn't affect other page flow.

I'd greatly like to figure out why I can't use a negative top margin on IE like I can with other browsers, so I'm still hoping someone can provide an answer that will provide all the benefits of a negative top margin but also work with IE8.

Comment: +1 for the title alone

Comment: Thanks :)  I'm starting to accept the fact that my site will probably just look like ass in IE.

Comment: Depending on who your expected audience is, that might still work

Comment: I can't see any difference, a look to to developer-tools shows that the margin has been applied.

Comment: Are you sure the  problem is setting the `marginTop` value and not that it doesn't have the effect you want? I.e. have you tried setting the CSS value by hand?
Your fiddle looks the same to me in IE8, IE9, Firefox and Rockmelt.

Comment: "I'm starting to accept the fact that IE will probably just make my site look like ass." - Fixed that for you.

Comment: @frozenkoi - Yes, setting the margin to 0 by hand works.  When I set the property with script, though I can confirm it gets updated in Developer Tools, the element is not re-drawn in IE.  Are you saying when you run my Fiddle in IE8, you see the "Name of new menu" text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trigger for this behaviour is how IE8 handles the fieldset element.

You can work around it by setting the display for fieldset to inline (or inline-block).

```
div.modal.addmenu fieldset {
   display: inline;   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't exactly a bug; it is just based on the fact that (to keep up in performance comparisons) IE was built since version 5.5 with a minimized preset of static definitions;

That means: Instead of spending any Element the whole and correct definition (depending on which god of specifications you hail out for ...) for the type it is, IE is using less.

---

*TODO:*
Give back what should be credited for acting as a top-model paragraph relatively positioned; **DISPLAY** it accordingly to its talents; any super-paragraph should do the catwalk **inline**, even if it is a *block*-head, you might try using sugar and whiplashes to remember your nasty P of its origin as a **inline-block**. It's a frenzy P, give some respect to its talents…

---

*DOJO:*
In fact, you as a rune-reading script-javalchemist be the one who has to have to take control over the brew the browser serves. Or it makes boom, silently ...

---

*GODO:*
Necessary things to do if you want to use negative-margins in browsers which don't play legally:

- remember the elements you want to use of their display's origin; don't believe in browser-vendors that they would have done that already for you
- - IF you are just out for IE 7+ use **display:inline-block;**
- - IF you want to get negative-margins to effect on all notable browsers, but can forget about NS4, then use **display:inline;** or **display:block;**
- Do not forget to build the foundation for your negative-margins: set **position:relative;**

---

*MOJO:*
If IE-Betas and older ones like 5.5 or 6 are in your point of interest, you have to ensure that your *relative-positioned negative-margin paragraph* has *values* for **width** and **height**; Depending on what you are trying to achieve, sometimes a **height:auto;** helps out.